# How to post parameters in jenkins? The Build Number of the first Job?

Tags: git, jenkins, environment-variables, jobs, git-tag

**JENKINS**

I am running `5 jobs`. The first triggers the second and so on. I am trying to pass the `$BUILD_NUMBER` environmental variable from the first job to the last one so I can use the `$BUILD_NUMBER` from the first job for a git tag in the last job.

I was wondering what is the best way to go about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the child job to paramatized with parameter BUILD_NUMBER.
Trigger build from the parent job with predefined parameters. 
Set them as
BUILD_NUMBER=$BUILD_NUMBER

Comment: This worked me so I just added the line tagNumber = $BUILD_NUMBER to pass to the next job. Then, I went in and added a string parameter to be accepted by the next job. That parameter was tagNumber. Then, I followed the process until the variable reached the last job.